SPA Как понять на чем написана html страница?
Теоретический вопрос. Можно ли имея только html DOM дерево определить на каком фреймворке/библиотеке написана страница ?
Предположим у вас есть парсер который дергает по указаному URL html страницы. Как определить, что именно собирает данную страницу Next|React|Vue... ? *Код данной страницы не ваш, что там будет в href= scr= предугадать сложно...

https://stackoverflow.com/q/56817526/4496422, https://gist.github.com/rambabusaravanan/1d594bd8d1c3153bc8367753b17d074b
